# How to make a ball go in a specific direction according to where it's clicked?

Tags: java, processing

```
    Table t1= new Table(300, 300);
float power=0;
float dx=0;
float dy=0;


void setup()
{
  size(1000, 600);
  frameRate(10);
}

void draw()
{
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke(0, 0, 0); 
  strokeWeight(10);
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  fill(26, 218, 35);
  rect(0, 0, 1000, 600);
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  ellipse(0, 0, 80, 80);
  ellipse(1000, 0, 80, 80);
  ellipse(0, 600, 80, 80);
  ellipse(1000, 600, 80, 80);
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke(0, 0, 0);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(t1.cue_ball.center.x, t1.cue_ball.center.y, 20, 20);

  dx=friction(dx);
  dy=friction(dy);


  if (mousePressed)
  {
    power+=5;
  }
 if (t1.cue_ball.center.x+30>1000 || t1.cue_ball.center.x-30<0)
  {
    dx*=-1;

  }
  if (t1.cue_ball.center.y+30 >=600 || t1.cue_ball.center.y -30<=0)
  {
    dy*=-1;
  }
  t1.cue_ball.center.x +=dx;
  t1.cue_ball.center.y +=dy;

}


void mouseReleased()
{
  dx=power*2;
  dy=power*2;
}
float friction (float c)
{
  c*=0.9;
  return c;
}

    class Ball 
{
  float rad;
  Point center;
  Point contact_point;
  color col;

  Ball ( float a, float b)
  {
    center = new Point (a+=dx, b+=dy);
    //contact_point= new Point(
  }
} 

class Table
{
  Ball [] b_arr;    
  Stick st;
  Ball cue_ball;

  Table ( float a, float b )
  {

    cue_ball= new Ball( a, b);
  }
}

class Point
{
  float x;
  float y;

  Point(float a, float b)
  {
    x=a;
    y=b;
  }
}

class Stick
{
  Point start_p;
  Point end_p;
  color col;
  int length;
}
```

So we want to add something so that when the ball is clicked, it will move accordingly.  For example, if it is clicked in the top left, it will move diagonally right down.  If clicked bottom left, it will move diagonally right up.  Also, is there a way to correspond this to the angle? So a larger angle between the click point and the center will make a steeper diagonal.

Added lines of code I'm not sure where needs to be added:

```
t1.cue_ball.center.x+=dx;
t1.cue_ball.center.y+=dy;
dx=t1.cue_ball.center.x-mouseX;
dy=t1.cue_ball.center.y-mouseY;
float n= sqrt(pow(dx,2)+pow(dy,2));
```

dx*=power/n;
  dy*=power/n;

Answer (score 1):

If you have or know how to compute the angle between the x-axis and the cue (I'm assuming this is billiards), then to make the ball go in that direction, if I understand your code correctly, you could just set the dx and dy of the ball that you strike according to

```
dx = power*cos(angle)
dy = power*sin(angle)
```

You might have to take the negative angle instead, depending on the coordinate system (if going up is positive or negative in the y-direction), and precisely what angle you compute. The easiest is probably to just plug it in and see what happens!

EDIT:
Not related to your question, but as a matter of style, it might be a good idea to move your logic for moving and drawing the ball to the Ball class. So that every tick, you draw the balls on the screen by calling an appropriate `draw()` method for each instance of the Ball class. Then it would be much easier to move several balls at once.

EDIT2:
I just realized you can actually solve the problem without trigonometry, if you know the point where you click. Let's say cx,cy is the point where you click, and x,y is the center of the ball, then your dx and dy for the ball can be computed as:

```
dx = x-cx
dy = y-cy
n = sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)

dx *= power/n
dy *= power/n
```

Explanation:
The outgoing velocity for the ball should be in the same direction as the click relative to the ball. So we already have the relative lengths of dx and dy, and to get the right power we just need to normalize and multiply by the power.

Comment: Yeah I knew to use to trig functions, but it's actually finding the angle im confused about.  Sorry if this is basic I'm really new to processing.  But here's what I was thinking that corresponds to what you wrote above.  So I'm thinking of having a seperate function like this:                                float angle(float a, float b) //float a is dx and float b is dy
{
  //calculating angle here (this is part I'm not sure how to do)
  
  return c;  //where c is the angle
}

Comment: dx=power*2*cos(angle(t1.cue_ball.center.x));
    dy=power*2*sin(angle(t1.cue_ball.center.y));

    float angle(float a, float b) //float a is center.x and float b is center.y
    {
  //calculating angle here (this is part I'm not sure how to do)
  
      return c;  //where c is the angle
    }

Comment: @Megann I thought of an easier solution (without the trig), so I edited the answer. (It's possible I messed up the signs of dx and dy - try it and see! If the ball rolls towards the click, change to dx = cx-x and dy = cy-y)

Comment: Ugh so I had it working, but it was a little jittery near the borders so I decided to try to move the lines somewhere else and now the ball won't move at all and anywhere I put it I cant get it back to at least moving? I put the added lines in my original post, I cant figure out how to add formatted code in comments.

Comment: It also randomly changed direction as the ball moving, even when i commented out the dx*=-1 and dy*=-1.

Comment: @Megann It sounds like maybe it's changing according to the mouse position every time the ball is updated. But you only want to change the dx and dy as above in the moment that you release the mouse button. So put it in the mouseReleased() method.